# Remove AJAX in views form (on change)

Tags: views, forms, ajax, panels

I have a problem with a views form. It should only be submitted when I hit the submit button. Currently it is submitting when I change a value in any textfield. When I select "Using AJAX: no" it doesn't change anything. :/

Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are talking about views exposed filters. right?

Comment: There are some exposed filters on the panel yes. The problem is when I'm changing a value in any textbox (not the search values) it shows the throbber and submits the form. But I want it to not do this and let me change any values I want and finally hit "submit".

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the settings in view as follows

1. Go to view and find Exposed Form (under Advanced).
2. Click on Settings

[image]

3.Uncheck 'Autosubmit' option to prevent 'Automatically submit the form once an element is changed'.

4.Click on Apply and save the view.

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this one, but this is for the exposed filters I have already found this. The problem is the panel has got a search bar on the top (exposed filters) and below there is the content which contains a table with some editable textfields. When I change a value inside any of these fields the throbber starts running and AJAX is doing it works. And this is what I need to get stopped :/

Comment: I've asked this as a new question because I was on the wrong way. Anyway you get a positive vote for the help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use [better_exposed_filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. You can disable autosubmit in Exposed form style in your views.